# parse error in php when trying to replace string

Tags: php, javascript

I have this line of code below:

```
     foreach ($searchResults as $key=>$question) {

 echo '<tr class="questiontd"><td>'.htmlspecialchars($question).'</td>';
 echo '<td class="optiontypetd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchOption[$key]).'</td>';
 echo '<td class="noofanswerstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchNoofAnswers[$key]).'</td>';
 echo '<td class="answertd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchAnswer[$key]).'</td>';
 echo '<td class="noofrepliestd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchReply[$key]).'</td>';
 echo '<td class="noofmarkstd">'.htmlspecialchars($searchMarks[$key]).'</td>';
 echo "<td class='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick=\"parent.addwindow('$question','$searchMarks[$key]','$searchNoofAnswers[$key]','$searchOption[$key]','$searchReply[$key]','$searchAnswer[$key]');\">Add</button></td></tr>";
}
```

Now I wanted to use str_repace to replace some string characters but when I do this I get this error in the line above:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in
>   ...text.php on line 154

How can I remove this error?

UPDATE:

OK I remove the single quote as mentioned but problem is that it messes my add button up. I am now getting this error when I click on the "Add" button:

> syntaxError: unterminated string literal error:
>
> parent.addwindow('!

The line of code where the error is displayed like this in the console:

```
<button type='button' class='add' onclick="parent.addwindow('!"�$%^&*()-=\'.,:;/?#~*/\\><'
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Use the heredoc syntax when outputting html/js -- you will find it easier to read and you will be less likely to make mistakes.

Comment: @Cups How do I use the heredoc syntax?

Comment: google `heredoc php` and achieve enlightenment!

Comment: try removing the single quotation mark (') after $question

Comment: The big gotcha is to NOT habitually indent your code when using heredoc.  This used to get me every time -- especially the last line!

Comment: @anditpainsme I removed the quote but then it gives me another problem

Comment: can you explain the other problem?

Comment: @anditpainsme I have included an update in the question so you can see the other problem

Comment: Why can you not add the comma outside of the str_replace() call? Like so: str_replace("'","\'", $question) . "'',  If it was required in there, use concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` is basically a quote mismatch. StackOverflow's syntax highlighter makes it more obvious with the color change.

```
$question')
```

Remove the single quote and you should be good.

Follow-up:

- [PHP Parser Tokens](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)
- [PHP String Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax)

#### Alternatives:

As [Cups](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173934/cups) mentioned, you can use `heredoc` (though I personally think it doesn't help in this particular scenario from a readability standpoint--you're still embedding a lot of variables within HTML syntax). Another method is to store the `parent.addwindow` arguments as a variable then pass it within the string (save yourself from both an extended echo line and worrying about quote mis-matches.  For example:

```
$addWindowArgs = "'" . implode("','", array(
  str_replace('"','&quot;', $question),
  $searchMarks[$key],
  $searchNoofAnswers[$key],
  $searchOption[$key],
  $searchReply[$key],
  $searchAnswer[$key]
)) . "'";

echo  "<td class=\"addtd\">"
    . "<button type=\"button\" class=\"add\" onclick=\"parent.addwindow({$addWindowArgs});\">Add</button>"
    . "</td></tr>";
```

Alternatively, you can use `sprintf` instead of `implode` with the same echo call:

```
$addWindowArgs = sprintf("'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'",
  str_replace('"','&quot;', $question),
  $searchMarks[$key],
  $searchNoofAnswers[$key],
  $searchOption[$key],
  $searchReply[$key],
  $searchAnswer[$key]
);
```

This gives you more control in case some arguments are numbers, some are strings, etc.

Comment: The problem is that if I remove that quote, then all of the variables go into the "Add" button which messes up the button so I need that quote, does it mean I need to put an extra quote somewhere? Lemme put an update on my question so you can see what the problem is

Comment: question updated so you can see the problem I have after I remove the quote

Comment: @user1701484: See my updated answer. (Your problem, as I see it, was _where_ you placed the single quote--It needed to be within a set of double quotes.

Comment: Hi sorry had to run an errand, I have posted the main code so you can see on top of the question what code looks like. Is it ok if you edit your answer to fit my code because when trying to do your method it is giving me problems because of the echos. It's only the $question variable giving me problems. Other variables won't encounter this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: its ok, ifigured it out, thanks for your help tho :)